# How to Remove Duplicate item in SQLite when Using ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I keep having duplicated items when getting data from SQLite using ListView, i am populating two TextView with data from two different columns in two different tables. When i use the individual data from each column and table they work as planned but together there are duplicated items.

From the database.java

```
public Cursor getQuestionAndAnswer(){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from Question_Table, Answer_Table" ,null);
    }
```

From the Cursor Adapter

```
public class QuestionAndAnswerAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public QuestionAndAnswerAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.q_a_layout,parent,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView Question = view.findViewById(R.id.text_question);
        String listQuestion = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("QUESTIONS"));
        Question.setText(listQuestion);

        TextView Answer = view.findViewById(R.id.text_answer);
        String listAnswer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ANSWERS"));
        Answer.setText(listAnswer);
    }
}
```

When binding the Adapter to the ListView

```
        questionCursor = myDataBaseClass.getQuestionAndAnswer();


if (questionCursor != null) {
            QuestionAndAnswerAdapter questionAndAnswerAdapter = new QuestionAndAnswerAdapter(this, questionCursor);
            QuestionList.setAdapter(questionAndAnswerAdapter);
        }


[![The first text is duplicated, while the second text displays correctly][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your db table schema, this is more or less just sudo code, but I think you might just need to alter your SQL statement.

```
 // give me ALL columns, from both tables
select * from Question_Table, Answer_Table
```

Where I think it looks like you're trying to match answers to the question.

```
// give me all columns from this table matched up with this ID from that table.
SELECT * FROM question_table JOIN answer_table ON question_table.id = answer_table.questionID
```

For some quick brushing up on SQL, Khan Acadamy has a great interactive learning path:

https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/sql-join-on-tables/5409956539006976

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `ID` for your database records and get it `unique` depending on the id, but, remember you can't add same data multiple times, for that case you can compare data if it exists in the `DB` then doesn't add else add it.

Comment: Please can you explain in detail what you meant by "use ID for your database record and get it unique"

Comment: please check this https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-primary-key/